# Magento 2 how to define js library

Tags: magento2, requirejs

How to define js Library in Magento 2

**if I use below method only js is calling**

```
var config = {

  deps: [
    "js/main",
    "js/jquery.min",
    "js/bootstrap.min"
  ],
  paths: {
    'jquery' : 'js/jquery.min',
    'bootstrap': 'js/bootstrap.min'
  }

};
```

after that my console has some core file have the issue

**

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
Uncaught Error: Script error for: jquery/jquery.mobile.custom
Uncaught Error: Script error for: jquery/jquery.cookie
Uncaught Error: Script error for: jquery/jquery-migrate
Uncaught Error: Script error for: jquery/jquery.metadata
Uncaught Error: Script error for: jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon
```

**

Comment: whats the problem you have faced?

Comment: First thing is not calling second is breacking all core js

Comment: check my updated answer and first run upgrade and then deploy command and check

Comment: Still same i checked my network tab thease js not calling

Comment: share your full js path.

Comment: like this --> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: remove jquery dependency in shim as per my updated answer.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya actually i need bootstrap i am using some bootstrap class so that i used bootstrap

Comment: you made changes on boostrap.js file?

Comment: What i need to change

Comment: no that is library file so no change

Comment: so you want to get boostrap.js file in your phtml file right

Comment: i want to this two all page <script src="js/jquery.min.js"/>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"/><script src="js/main.js"/>

Comment: by default jquery and bootstrap.js file is library file and you want extra main.js file in all page.

Comment: Yes Correct ......

Comment: <script>
   require([
      'jquery',
      'main',      
      'mage/bootstrap',
      'domReady!'
   ], function ($,main) {
     //your code
   });
</script> you can call your all js file using above way in any page usinjg phtml.

Comment: I already tried if i call like this what ever we mwntion it's not callling

Comment: show your code which you have tried

Comment: var config = { 
 paths: 
 { 
  'owlcarousel': 'js/owl.carousel.min', 
  'main' : 'js/main',
  },
   shim: { 
     'owlcarousel': { deps: ['jquery'] }, 
     'main': { deps: ['jquery'] }
     } 
};

Comment: after that i goto network tab then i search main.js it's not comming

Comment: where you have define your require js file

Comment: app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/requirejs-config.js

Comment: please update your question with only your requirejs-config.js file and in which file you have tried in phtml, remaining content will remove from question

Comment: Check my updated Question

Comment: keep in requirejs-config.js with only below,var config = { paths: { 'owlcarousel': 'js/owl.carousel.min', 'main' : 'js/main', }, shim: { 'owlcarousel': { deps: ['jquery'] }, 'main': { deps: ['jquery'] } } };

Comment: If i use that main.js & owlcarousel also not calling

Answer (score 3):

> For module level,

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            main: 'Packagename_Modulename/js/main',
            jqueryMin: 'Packagename_Modulename/js/jquery.min',
            bootstrapMin: 'Packagename_Modulename/js/bootstrap.min'
        }
    }
};
```

filepath of js will be,

```
app/code/Packagename/Modulename/view/frontend/web/js/main.js
app/code/Packagename/Modulename/view/frontend/web/js/jquery.min.js
app/code/Packagename/Modulename/view/frontend/web/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

> For theme level,

```
 var config = {
        map: {
            '*': {
                main: 'js/main',
                jqueryMin: 'js/jquery.min',
                bootstrapMin: 'js/bootstrap.min'
            }
        }
    };
```

filepath of js will be,

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/web/js/main.js
app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/web/js/jquery.min.js
app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/web/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

> Update Using paths and Shim requirejs

```
var config = {
    paths: { 
            'jquery': 'js/jquery.min',
            'bootstrap': 'js/bootstrap.min',
            'owlcarousel': 'js/owl.carousel.min',            
            'main' : 'js/main'
    },
    shim: {
        'bootstrap':{
            'deps': ['jquery']
        },
        'owlcarousel':{
            'deps': ['jquery']
        },
        'main': {
            'deps': ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: it's in a main web folder in my custom theme

Comment: I added file in this location app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/requirejs-config.js but it's not calling is there any commands to be run after adding

Comment: even i run all commands but still it's not calling

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: Still same that js not even calling also

Comment: Check my updated Question

Comment: @rake sh, you  good frontend  knowledge bro :)

Answer (score 3):

In your `require.js` file you can add like this,

```
var config = {    
    paths: {
        'yourbootstrap': 'YOURVENDOR_MODULENAME/js/bootstrap'        
    },
    shim: {
        'yourbootstrap': {
            'deps': ['jquery']
        }        
    }
};
```

Note:: here I added `shim` because bootstrap js is depends on `jquery`, if you are using custom js and it is not depends on `jquery` then you can remove it

Now, put your bootstrap in `YOURVENDOR_MODULENAME` module in js directory. path should be,

```
app\code\YOURVENDOR\MODULENAME\view\frontend\web\js
```

and execute the command for static content deploy `php bin/magento s:s:d`

Now if you want to use bootstrap js in your phtml then you can just simply add by using,

```
require(['jquery', 'domReady!','yourbootstrap'], function(jQuery,yourbootstrap){


});
```

Comment: it's in a main web folder in my custom theme

Comment: Check my updated question

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps I took, just replace my references to Slick slider with your library.

### Add an alias

I always add my scripts to the Require config so I can reference them via an alias:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            slick: 'js/vendor/slick/slick.min'
        }
    }
};
```

### Initialise your JS

You can use either `data-mage-init` or `x-magento-init` methods, in this example I'll use `data-mage-init`:

```
<div class="large-carousel" data-mage-init='{"slick": {
"dots": true
}}'>
    <div class="large-carousel__slide">
        <a href="#">
            <h2>Slide 1</h2>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="large-carousel__slide">
        <a href="#">
            <h2>Slide 2</h2>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="large-carousel__slide">
        <a href="#">
            <h2>Slide 3</h2>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Result

And here I have my carousel which can easily be reused with different options.

[image]

#### To debug

As a lot of the code inside your Require JS config seems unnecessary try something like to get the syntax correct first:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            'bootstrap': 'js/bootstrap.min'
        }
    },
    shim: {
        'bootstrap': {
            'deps': ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

And see if that gives you an errors.

Comment: Hi My problem is libreary is not calling

Comment: So you've tried the above but the file is 404ing? If so what is the file path to your JS?

Comment: Check my updated Question

Comment: Are you adding your own jQuery? If so this is why you have issues, jQuery is already available to require so by adding your own you're causing conflicts.

Comment: Remove your references to `jquery` and see what happens then.

Comment: You mean path section

Comment: All the sections, deps, paths, and shim for now. If you get an error with bootstrap you can add the shim back but I don't think you need the other references. I never use them and all my jQuery plugins work fine.

Comment: What I've done in my example is all I had to do to get my carousel working. So the only additional step you may need is the shim.

Comment: Now i got this error only Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Comment: If that's the only error we're making progress! Now try adding the shim back (for bootstrap only).

Comment: like this var config = {

  deps: [
    "js/main",
    /*"js/jquery.min",*/
    "js/bootstrap.min"
  ],
  paths: {
   /*'jquery' : 'js/jquery.min',*/
    'bootstrap': 'js/bootstrap.min'
  },
  shim: {
   'jquery': {
      deps: ['jquery']
    },
    'bootstrap': {
      deps: ['jquery']
    }

  }

};

Comment: Great part is here, as usual you do. Thanks Sir :)

Comment: That seems to have syntax errors @Magento2 - I have updated my answer with a short example, see what happens with that.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I faced a similar issue before for slick, here is what I did

> 1. create a file in your theme directory

`{theme_dir}/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            slick: 'js/slick.min',
                    rellax: 'js/rellax'
                }
            },
};
```

> 2. add your plugin file in

`{theme_dir}/web/js`

You can then add your JS code in file or a main js file

```
require([
            'jquery',
            'slick'
        ], function ($) {
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $(".images-grid-main.mobile_slider").slick({
                    slidesToShow: 2,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                    autoplay: true,
                    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
                    nextArrow: '<div class="arrows next-arrow"></div>',
                    prevArrow: '<div class="arrows prev-arrow"></div>',
                });
            });
    });
```

Similarly, you can use this logic for your code.